# "I will come by the train" vs. "I will come by train" - do we need the article here?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> I will come **by the train**.

Is it correct or we need to remove "**the**". Give reason also.

Comment: "I will come by train" is the correct. You dont need "the" because its useless.

Comment: @sNexy "The" is needed if the context provides a specific train and not a "train" in general.

Comment: Yeah you are right but in this text "train" is general so "the" is not needed.

Comment: Yes, Now Iam agree with you. As it is in General Context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referring to a *mode*, the article is omitted:

> They arrived *by boat*.
>
> We will ship this item *by air*.
>
> We will go there *by train*.
>
> The politician communicated with his base *by tweet*.
>
> The train conductors union is on strike so we will have to go *by bus*.

Comment: Yes, Iam satisfied with your Answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'll mention that if it is a specific vehicle we would use the article, but we would use a different preposition - ***They arrived on a/the boat***.  Additionally, consider ***They arrived by way of boat***